# How to webscrape nested div and ol classes

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, twitter, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape [this webpage](https://twitter.com/search?f=images&vertical=news&q=Iran).

I am looking to download some photos from the 'photo-stream container', but without any success. Below is the codeblock I am currently working with.

Looking for all span classes that start with 'Adaptive'
As an example class would be "AdaptiveStreamGridImage grid-tweet has-cards has-content enabled clear first-row hoverZoomLink"

Any advice?

```py
d = requests.get('https://twitter.com/search?f=images&amp;vertical=news&amp;q=Iran').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(d, 'html.parser')

spans = soup.findAll("span", {"class": lambda x: x and x.startswith('Adaptive')})
print(spans)
```

I am receiving an empty list when printing 'spans'

```
[]
```

Comment: Did you check the page source for the existence of the elements you wish to seek?

Comment: I am looking for the span class that contains the word "Adaptive" - which was found during inspecting the page

Comment: I recommend using `soup.select('span[class^=Adaptive]')`, more cool by using css selectors

Comment: You're aware of the Twitter Terms of Service that prohibits web scraping, I hope? (section 4 under "Using the Services" https://twitter.com/en/tos) - It could cause your IP address to be banned. Why not use the API?

Answer (score 0):

The content that you want is most probably hidden with the power of JS scripts. Our `request` library is something which doesn't bother about those JS scripts and fetches the contents which would be visible to you in your JS less mode of your browser.
This issue can be resolved with the help of [`selenium`](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/) library. It allows you to load your webpage and it's contents just like any other browser that you use.
Hence a bit of workaround using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#Initiate your browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
#It's Firefox in my case, you can have Chrome or Safari or Opera, depending upon the webdriver you have installed in your system
url = 'https://twitter.com/search?f=images&amp;vertical=news&amp;q=Iran'
#Fetch the URL in the 'browser'
browser.get(url)
#Get the page source of the browser
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
#This page source is pretty similar to the one you see in your inspect element
browser.close() #'browser' has finished it's work, so 'close()' it
#Now apply whatever function you wish to on the webpage
spans = soup.findAll("span", {"class": lambda x: x and x.startswith('Adaptive')})
print(spans)
```